# Error while running spring boot jar packaged with spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Getting issue while running a spring boot jar created from thin-layout spring package

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot locate launcher: /root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher/1.0.23.RELEASE/spring-boot-thin-launcher-1.0.23.RELEASE-exec.jar
at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.launch(ThinJarWrapper.java:132)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.wrapper.ThinJarWrapper.main(ThinJarWrapper.java:107)

The Jar is deployed on AWS ECS as scheduled task and was working before few days and now started giving error.